# Is an Einstein-Rosen Bridge theoretically required to have matching Schwarzchild radii on either end?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, wormholes, white-holes

Is there a solution where the mouths on either end can have a different radius? I am also curious about these types of requirements in the case of a multi-mouth wormhole. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

The Einstein-Rosen bridge does require matching the same radius on both sides because the throat is formed by identifying 2-spheres on both sides.
The ER bridge is derived by applying transformation $u^2=r-2M$ to Schwarzschild metric, which is given by
$$
    d s^{2}=-\frac{u^{2}}{u^{2}+2 M} d t^{2}+4\left(u^{2}+2 M\right) d u^{2}+\left(u^{2}+2 M\right)^{2} d \Omega^{2},
$$
where $d\Omega^2$ is the metric of a 2-sphere and $-\infty<u<\infty$. It has a throat at $u=0$ and the area of the throat of the ER bridge is $4\pi(2M)^2$.
If you want to glue 2-spheres with different radii, then the spacetime is not continuous at the throat (the radius undergoes a sudden change), which is not what we want.

Comment: Thanks that what I was expecting (although I was hoping that was not the case). What about the case of multi-mouth wormholes? Would the radii have to add together in a certain way?

Comment: @Shedbot I don't know too much about multi-mouth wormholes. but I think if you add a mouth to a two-mouth wormhole, you can have a different throat area, which somehow means you glue spacetime with a different radius.  However, adding a mouth to a two-mouth wormhole is not trivial due to stability. One example of the three-mouth wormhole is shown in Figure 4 in [2012.07821](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.07821).

Answer (score 2):

The fact is that the E-R bridge has only one radius! you have singularities situated in the past timelike infinity and future timelike infinity and a spacelike connection because of the time-reversal symmetry of the Schwarzchild metric (if you sent $t \rightarrow -t$,
$ds^2$ is unchanged). So you can't have E-R bridge from Schwarzchild that brokes this property. Note that this type of B.H. is unphysical because eternal B.H. doesn't exist. All the black holes are borned from something like a collapsing star for example. So the real metric of a B.H. shouldn't have this type of symmetry. In the end a real B.H. have only one singularity (the one situated in the future timelike infinity) and can't be a wormhole.

Comment: Schwarzschild singularities are spacelike, not timelike.

Comment: You right, what i was tryng to say is that the two singularities are situated in the future timelike infinity, and past timelike infinity because of the time reversal symmetry of Shcwarzchild B.H.( aka eternal B.H.)